# Is is possible to to have a depends on a jQuery remote validation?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery remote validation to check if the description is already being used.

```
 Description: {
                    required: true,
                    maxlength: 20,
                    remote: function () {
                        var newDescription = $("#txtDescription").val();
                        var dataInput = { geoFenceDescription: newDescription };
                        var r = {
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "/ATOMWebService.svc/DoesGeoFenceDescriptionExist",
                            data: JSON.stringify(dataInput),
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "json",
                            dataFilter: function (data) {
                                var x = (JSON.parse(data)).d;
                                return JSON.stringify(!x);
                            }
                        };
                        return r;
                    }
                },
```

The problem I have is that this remote validation occurs when the user has NOT modified the text box and comes back saying the description has been used because it found it self in the database.

So is it possible to only run the remote validation if the text field is different to what was originally in it?

I noticed the the jQuery required validation has a depends option, but I couldn't get it to work with the remote call.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a solution for using `remote` with `depends`: https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/431

Comment: If anyone notices that this solution breaks at any point when the library is updated please post an alternate workaround; hopefully if the library changes in a way that breaks this workaround it provides a defined way to use these two together in the same version :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of the fact that jquery validate only accesses the "param" property of a rule if depends returns true, and the fact you can nest a remote in the "param" property;

```
    rules: {
      Description: {
        required: true,
        maxlength: 20,
        remote: {
          param: {
            url: URL,
            data: {
              // your data
            }
          },
          depends: function() {
            //depends returns true if ok to go
            return true || false;
          }
        }
      },
```

[Source (See `normalizeRules` around like 1278)](https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation/blob/master/src/core.js)